# Making DIV height at least as tall as the page in CSS

Tags: css, height

I have a DIV that I want to touch the bottom of the screen (for appearance reasons). Sometimes the content is enough tall to do that, but sometimes the content is too short and the DIV won't touch the bottom of the screen. Is there a simple workaround?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you set min-height to 100% for the DIV, you also need to include:

```
body, html {
   height:100%
}
```

Elements expand to the size of their container, so make sure the container (being the page itself) has a height of 100% as well.

Comment: Almost works. The DIV with min-height: 100%; works as expected, but how do I make DIVs inside it to height: 100%?

Comment: Please post a simple HTML example.

Comment: I realize this is a very old post, but as of now this doesn't work for me. The next solution below (with 'vh') did, though.

Answer (score 14):

For anyone reading this later (as I am) you can use

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

The `vh` unit stands for viewport height and is a percent of the screen size.

Comment: Much more straightforward and helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that this causes a problem on iPhone (Safari) as the bar appears above part of the element with height of 100vh

Answer (score 7):

This is way to do it: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 4):

min-height:100%

should work assuming it's not in another div with a height set,

Comment: good, if more people ignored ie6, perhaps people would stop using it :)

Comment: This will work in some browsers, but the body and html elements are content height only unless otherwise specified in some common broswers.

Comment: I can't get this to work? Are you sure it works? I tried Opera 10.50, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 4 and didn't work.

Comment: Try setting body, html { height:100%; } too, as per the answer below/above depending where it appears. :)

Answer (score 3):

IE6 fix to go along with Jimmeh's answer:

```
height: expression( this.scrollHeight < document.body.clientHeight ? "100%" : "auto" )
```

Comment: I think that `height: 100%` is enough - IE6 will set auto height if not hidden overflow (or it decides that because of whatever obscure reason, height should be *anything else*)

Answer (score 1):

If you set the div's CSS to position:absolute you can use:

```
.yourDiv {
  top: 0
  bottom: 0

}
```

Comment: This will only work if the div is not placed inside of another element with position set (not display).  And if that is the case, the html and body elements must be set to have 100% height.

Comment: True. I was assuming (perhaps wrongly) that this was going to be the main container div. Otherwise, why make it stretch top to bottom?

Comment: I don't stretch it from top to bottom, but from y to bottom where y is a position depending on the upper DIV elements (menu and header).